# What's the definition of array get arrayname 12,*

Tags: tcl

I have a code starting with

```
array set arrayname 
array get arrayname 12,*
```

Can anyone explain me the definition of second line

```
array get arrayname 12,*
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do:

```
array get arrayname 12,*
```

Then the result will be the keys and values of the array called `arrayname`, **filtered by a [glob pattern](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M35)** such that each key begins with the characters `12,`. Glob patterns are like a super-simplified version of regular expressions: `*` means any characters, `?` means any *one* character, bracketed terms `[…]` to say “any of these chars”, and all matches are anchored at both ends of the string.

The result of `array get` is always a dictionary; it might be an empty dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Just a demo

```
% array set arrayname {
    1,a one
    2,b two
    3,c three
    4,d four
    5,e five
    6,f six
    7,g seven
    8,h eight
    9,i nine
    10,j ten
    11,k eleven
    12,l twelve
    13,m thirteen
    12,n fourteen
}
% array get arrayname
2,b two 11,k eleven 3,c three 12,l twelve 4,d four 12,n fourteen 13,m thirteen 5,e five 6,f six 7,g seven 8,h eight 1,a one 9,i nine 10,j ten
% array get arrayname 12,*
12,l twelve 12,n fourteen
```

Comment: So is it possible to call every number in arrayname by.  % array get arrayname  ,* or is there any special code to call every element???

Comment: You can either omit the pattern, or use the pattern `*`. The pattern `,*` means "starts with a comma". `*.*` means "contains a comma". Check the documentation.